# sorting date pipe in ascending order using custom date pipe in angular 12

Tags: angular, sorting, date-pipe

Hi I'm trying to sort the dates in ascending order instead of decending. This is the code I that I have currently.

custome.pipe.ts

```
import {pipe, pipetransform} from '@angular/core';
import * moment from 'moment'

@pipe({
 name: 'customDate'
})

export class customDatePipe implements pipeTransform{
 transform(value: number | Date, formate?: string): string {
  if(value){
  const local = navigator.language;
  if(!format){
  format = 'L';
}
return moment(value, format, local).format(format);
}
return '-';
}
}
```

Cards.ts

```
@input() title: string;
@inpur() eventId: string;
@input() date: Date;

toString(date: Date){
 return new Date(date?.toString()?.slice(0, -1))
}
```

card.html

```
<div {{toString(date) | customDate}}></div>
```

event-list.html

```
    <app-cards
    *ngFor="let event of projectEventList.projectsEvents"
     (cardClick)="onClick($event, true);
      [date]="getDate(event.eventDescription)"><app-cards>
```

event-list.ts

```
    <privatr getProjectEvents(projectId: number){
  this.projectEventSubscription = this.eventService.getProjectEvents(projectId).subscribe(events: PlukEvent[]) => {
event.sort(a:plukEvent, b:PlukEvent) =>(a.eventDate > b.eventDate ? 1 : b.event > a.eventDate ? -1 : 0))

this.projectEvents = events;
this.projectEventListSerive.setProjectEvent(events)
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see any sort-related code  only date formatting. Please add the sorting behavior

Comment: Hi mox i was hoping someone could help me with that i have been search on the internet for a while now i cant seem to get the right method for sorting in ascending order

Comment: Add the code of Card's parent

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm the parent compoent is so complicated. is there no method that you can help me with by just using the custom' date pipe

Comment: No, the date pipe is not related to sorting and can't effect that. The parent likely contains some kind of array that is used to create the cards with an ngFor. That array must be sorted.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm ok il include the code from the parent

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm should i add both the ts and html ?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i included the parents component code

Comment: try change this `event.sort(a:plukEvent, b:PlukEvent) =>(a.eventDate > b.eventDate ? 1 : b.event > a.eventDate ? -1 : 0))` to `event.sort(a:plukEvent, b:PlukEvent) =>(a.eventDate > b.eventDate ? -1 : b.event > a.eventDate ? 1 : 0))`

Comment: @efkah still getting the same order